# Determinant of a Matrix using js

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, matrix

I am learning DSA. I've learned about recursion approximately 20 days ago and solved some easy questions like decimal to binary, binary to decimal, Fibonacci series. For a medium difficulty, I was trying to solve how to find the determination of a matrix. I've completed 70% of the code yesterday and was stuck with **stack overflow** problem or **maximum call stack exceeded**. Today I completed my code and my code is running perfectly. The problem is I don't know **how the hell my code is working!!** Can anybody explain please!

First I created the pseudocode and then I coded. Please explain how the summing of the coefficient is working and why recursion don't work if I modify the main matrix and why I have to create a copy of the matrix and then input it again in the same function.

Note: I am a **beginner** and self-taught js programmer and my coding skill is horrible.

```
function DeterminantOfMatrix(matrix) {
    let givenMatrix = matrix;
    let validInput = true;

    //input validation
    let columnLength = givenMatrix.length;
    givenMatrix.forEach(row => row.length !== columnLength ? validInput = false : false);
    if (!validInput) return "Input a valid n*n matrix";

    // determining the matrix using 1st row.
    //strippedMatrix will remove ignored row and column

    function strippedMatrix(matrix, index) {
        if (matrix.length === 2 || matrix.length === 0) return matrix;
        let givenMatrix = matrix;
        let resultMatrix = [];
        //Eleminating ignored row and column
        for (let i = 0; i < givenMatrix.length; i++) {
            let container = [];
            for (let j = 0; j < givenMatrix[i].length; j++) {
                if (j !== index) {
                    container.push(givenMatrix[i][j]);
                }
            }

            resultMatrix.push(container);
        }

        resultMatrix.shift();
        return resultMatrix;
    }

    //Never mutate the input of a recursive function
    //Make a copy and then mutate it
    function recursiveDeterminantMatrix(matrix) {
        let mat = matrix;
        let copyMat = matrix;
        if (mat.length === 2 && mat[0].length === 2) {
            let result = mat[0][0] * mat[1][1] - mat[0][1] * mat[1][0];
            return result;
        } else {
            //sum all the value of the cofactor

            let answer = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
                let cofactor =
                    (-1) ** i * mat[0][i] * recursiveDeterminantMatrix(strippedMatrix(copyMat, i));
                answer += cofactor;
            }
            return answer;
        }
    }

    return recursiveDeterminantMatrix(givenMatrix);
}


//Tests

DeterminantOfMatrix([
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [4, 5, 6, 7],
    [8, 9, 6, 7],
    [3, 2, 3, 1],
]); //-12

// DeterminantOfMatrix([
//     [1, 2, 3],
//     [4, 5, 6],
//     [8, 9, 6],
// ]); // 12

// DeterminantOfMatrix([
//     [1, 2],
//     [8, 9],
// ]); // -7
```

Comment: Please don't repeat asking the same question. Edit the [deleted one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68972044/determinant-of-a-matrix) and turn it in to a question that is fit for this site. So I repeat here: I don't understand the question. You had a problem, and fixed it, and now you don't understand why it got fixed? Although some things could be improved in your code, there is not much we can say other than what you already know, since you coded it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple reason you shouldn't mutate the object passed through a recursive function: if you need it again, you've lost the original.  This happens with a determinant function because the mutations will recur on a subproblem with a specific row and column removed, but then you need to do it again removing the same row, but a different column:

```
det (
  |1 2 3 4|
  |4 5 6 7|
  |8 9 6 7|
  |3 2 3 1|
) = 
1 * det (   -  2 * det (  +   3 * det ( -  4 * det (
  |       |      |       |      |       |    |       |
  |  5 6 7|      |4   6 7|      |4 5   7|    |4 5 6  |
  |  9 6 7|      |8   6 7|      |8 9   7|    |8 9 6  |
  |  2 3 1|      |3   3 1|      |3 2   1|    |3 2 3  |
)              )              )            )
```

So we need to take the elements of the first row, multiply them by the determinants of the matrix found ignoring the first row and the column containing that element, and then alternate adding and subtracting the results.

Now imagine you were not creating copies but instead actually deleting rows and columns.

Our first subproblem would involve taking the 1 from the first column of the first row, removing the rest of that row and column, leaving us with

```
|5 6 7|
|9 6 7|
|2 3 1|
```

whose determinant we've found recursively.  Then we would proceed with the `2` in the second column of the first row... no wait, that `2` is now gone!  And this is the problem.  We can't find the

```
|4 6 7|
|8 6 7|
|3 3 1|
```

we need for the second subproblem, since the first column was *already removed*.  This is the issue.

We should note that some simple recursions don't share this issue since they make exactly one use of their input data, and no subsequent steps need it again.  But it's a good habit to be in to simply avoid mutating the input data to any recursive function, and you won't get into trouble.

So we need to use our input data immutably.  We can do this by making defensive copies when it's passed in or when make the recursive call.

Modern JS makes it much simpler, though, to make copies of our matrix.  Here's another solution that I find much cleaner than the above:

```js
const sum = (xs) =>
  xs . reduce ((a, b) => a + b, 0)
  
const excluding = (i) => (xs) => 
  [... xs .slice (0, i), ...xs .slice (i + 1)]

const determinant = ([xs, ...xss]) => 
  xs .length == 1
    ? xs [0]
    : sum (xs .map (
        (x, i) => (-1) ** i * x * determinant (xss .map (excluding (i)))
      ))
                                       

console .log (determinant ([
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [4, 5, 6, 7],
  [8, 9, 6, 7],
  [3, 2, 3, 1],
])) //=>-12

console .log (determinant ([
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [8, 9, 6],
])) //=> 12

console .log (determinant ([
  [1, 2],
  [8, 9],
])) //=> -7
```

Because your question was about why an earlier attempt wasn't working while the immutable version was, which we've already answered, I won't go into detail here on this code, but we should note how we handle this immutably.  First, using destructuring, we separate the first matrix row from the remaining ones, naming them `xs` and `xss`.  Then the helper function, `excluding` takes an index and an array and returns an array with all the elements before and after that index, but not the index itself.

This would be an alternate way to do something similar, and you might find it easier to read:

```js
const stripRowAndCol = (r, c) => (matrix) =>
  matrix .filter ((_, j) => j !== r)
      .map (row => row .filter ((_, i) => i !== c))
                              

const determinant = (matrix) => 
  matrix [0] .length == 1
    ? matrix [0] [0]
    : sum (matrix [0] .map (
        (x, i) => (-1) ** i * x * determinant (stripRowAndCol (0, i) (matrix))
      ))
```

### A note for next time

The comment from trincot was correct.  It is hard to make a legitimate attempt to answer this question, when you only show us the *working* code.  You bury the lede, and don't include anything about the mutable vs immutable question at hand in the title.  It's easy to read your question as simply, "Why does this code I wrote work?", usually off-limits for StackOverflow.

So next time, perhaps something like this would be better:

> ### Why does my recursion not work when I mutate the input?
>
> I wrote the code below, and can only get it to work if I clone my input
> before making a recursive call.  Why is that?
>
> I'm learning about recursion and have solved some easier problems such as ... but now I'm trying to calculate the determinant of a matrix.  I tried it like this:
>
> ```
> ....  ... <broken code here> ..
> .. ........ ...
> .... ..... . .....
> ...
> ```
>
> But this fails to calculate correctly, giving me these errors: ...
>
> When I switch to this, it works fine:
>
> ```
> ....  ... <working code here> ..
> .. ....  .... ...
> .... ... ..... . ... ..
> ... .. .
> ```
>
> The only difference between them is that the working one copies the array
> before I work with it.
>
> Why does this make a difference?  I would expected them to work the same, and the first one to be much faster.  What am I missing?